# Making high resolution map in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, graphics

How to make a high-resolution map in ArcGIS?

I have a map scale on 1:1.000.000, I have a label in the annotations scale (1:2.500) and set data frame scale on 1:1.000.

I tried to export it on resolution 1.000 dpi (jpeg/pdf/png) but when I zoomed the map it's still blurry, I can't see my labels on it.

[image: My_output]

I want to make a map similar to this

[image: Desired_output]

Does anyone know how to make it?

Comment: Are you in layout view? Have you tried increasing dpi setting?

Comment: do you have any layer with transparency?

Comment: @BERA: yes i am. ive tried it but on jpeg the max dpi i can afford is 2000. More than that arcgis dont allowed me to export in jpeg..

Comment: @florjan: i uncheck that on my layer properties and set transparency to 0%.. or are ther other way to do it?

Comment: Are you saying the annotation is set to a reference scale of 1:2500, or are you just showing us that scale here?

Comment: That is the way, sometimes i get this issue when i had layer with transparency. Try to convert it to PDF, if PDF is exported into vector than you are OK (you can export from PDF to JPG with high quality).